# How to make a null date display as a 0

Tags: sql-server, isnull

I have the select statement.  I am trying to make the t.Date2 column appear as a 0 instead of a null.  As you can see I used the IsNull to show nulls as a 0.  The problem is that the field is a datetime field so instead of showing 0 it shows 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000.  Is there a way to make it show just a 0?

```
SELECT t.Name, t.Number, t.Status, t.Date1, IsNull(t.Date2, 0),
    DateDiff(mi, t.Date2, GetDate()) AS TimeIdleMinutes
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `datetime` value can't have the value `0`, so you would need to use a type that could hold both a representation of a date and `0`. That would for example be a `varchar` value.

Example:

```
IsNull(convert(varchar(25), t.Date2, 120), '0')
```